# create batch file from batch or how do i write non executed code

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to create a batch file from another batch. So how do i write code inside a new bat, without executing it inside the original?
My code so far is:

```
SET var1=%~dp0
SET var2
for %%a in ("%cd%") do set var2=%%~na
echo bla %var1% bla >> build%var2%.bat
```

Instead of the "bla" there should be multiple lines of code. How do I archive this?

Edit:

now my code looks like this:

```
SET var1=%~dp0
SET var2
for %%a in ("%cd%") do set var2=%%~na

SET string = (
echo SET mdbname=%var2%
echo SET OfficeDIR=%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Microsoft Office\Office14
echo SET WorkDIR=%var1%
echo md build

echo copy %%mdbname%%.mdb build\%%mdbname%%.mda /Y
echo "%%officedir%%\msaccess.exe" /compact "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" 

echo "D:****.exe" "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" "D:\****** Key - Nicht weitergeben" "%%officedir%%"

echo copy "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" "%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\*******" /Y
)
echo %string% >> built%var2%.bat
```

But inside the new created batch there is only written: "ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON)." / "ECHO is activated (ON)."

Edit2:

now it looks this, and there happens nothing, not even a file is created

```
SET var1=%~dp0
SET var2
for %%a in ("%cd%") do set var2=%%~na

(echo SET mdbname=%var2%
echo SET OfficeDIR=%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Microsoft Office\Office14
echo SET WorkDIR=%var1%
echo md build

echo copy %%mdbname%%.mdb build\%%mdbname%%.mda /Y
echo "%%officedir%%\msaccess.exe" /compact "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" 

echo "D:\TFS\RepV\RepV 6.1\ITPBuildTool61.exe" "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" "D:\TFS\RepV\RepV 6.1\ITPEAK.OLKey Private Key - Nicht weitergeben" "%%officedir%%"

echo copy "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" "%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Sage\Office Line\6.1\Addin\Work" /Y) > built%var2%.bat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19817174/891976) here is your code with the applied principle.

```
@echo off
set "var1=%~dp0"
set "var2="
for %%A in ("%cd%") do set "var2=%%~nA"

(
echo @echo off
echo set "mdbname=%var2%"
echo set "OfficeDIR=%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Microsoft Office\Office14"
echo set "WorkDIR=%var1%"
echo md build

echo copy "%%mdbname%%.mdb" "build\%%mdbname%%.mda" /Y
echo "%%officedir%%\msaccess.exe" /compact "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" 

echo "D:\TFS\RepV\RepV 6.1\ITPBuildTool61.exe" "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" "D:\TFS\RepV\RepV 6.1\ITPEAK.OLKey Private Key - Nicht weitergeben" "%%officedir%%"

echo copy "%%WorkDir%%\build\%%mdbname%%.mda" "%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\Sage\Office Line\6.1\Addin\Work" /Y
) > built%var2%.bat

echo %cd%
type built%var2%.bat
pause
```

This works for me and creates a file with the following contents in the working directory.

```
@echo off
set "mdbname=Desktop"
set "OfficeDIR=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14"
set "WorkDIR=C:\Users\User\Desktop\"
md build
copy "%mdbname%.mdb" "build\%mdbname%.mda" /Y
"%officedir%\msaccess.exe" /compact "%WorkDir%\build\%mdbname%.mda"
"D:\TFS\RepV\RepV 6.1\ITPBuildTool61.exe" "%WorkDir%\build\%mdbname%.mda" "D:\TFS\RepV\RepV 6.1\ITPEAK.OLKey Private Key - Nicht weitergeben" "%officedir%"
copy "%WorkDir%\build\%mdbname%.mda" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Sage\Office Line\6.1\Addin\Work" /Y
```

Comment: thanks, this works great. but could you explain to me what the "@echo off" and "echo %cd% type built%var2%.bat" does? i thought i create the file with the "something > built%var2%.bat" statement.

Comment: using @ as the first character in a batch command suppresses the printing of the command to the window, much like `echo off` does for the rest of the lines. combining both of these into a single line, `@echo off`, means that the batchfile runs silently.  `echo %cd%` will show you the current directory on screen, and the `type built%var2%.bat` will show you the batch file that was written out - these lines may be removed once you are happy everything works

Answer (score 2):

Echo all lines with `echo` and escape all special characters.
`&|<>` needs a caret in front or quotes.
`%` needs to be doubled.

```
(
  echo @echo off
  echo echo This is batch2
  echo set var=abc
  echo echo %%var%%
  echo echo redirect ^> file2.ttx
) > build%var2%.bat
```

Comment: i did what you told me, outcome was not satisfying. but there are no errors anymore.

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink  Please show and specify how the "outcome was not satisfying" by updating your question.

Comment: @David Ruhmann i did this before, look after the "Edit:" part

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink `SET string = (` is not valid.  Make sure to output the parentheses block directly to the file. `) > build%var2%.bat`

Comment: @David Ruhrmann i made an edit in my question, now nothing happens when i execute the .bat